# How do you handle (or block) the sending of emails during integration testing within a Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-mvc, integration-testing

Perhaps I am not using the right search keywords but I cannot find anything on the subject of emails within integration tests. The word "mail" doesn't even appear once in the [docs on Testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html).

I would like to know if it is even possible to check if a Spring application is trying to send an email, and more importantly, how do I simulate it or block it from actually trying to contact an SMTP server every time I run my integration tests?

This wouldn't be much of a SO question without any code, so here's what I've got:

```
@Test
public void testResendConfirmationEmail() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/resend").principal(getSpoofedPrincipal()))
            .andExpect(status().isFound())
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/notactive"));
}
```

As you can see, I'm using Spring's MockMVC as the main entry point for my integration tests, in this case the resending of a confirmation email.

So how do I:

1. Block it from sending any emails?
2. Check that it sent the right email?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could set up a fake email server using [dumbster](https://github.com/kirviq/dumbster). Then you could send it and confirm that it arrives without actually requiring a recipient.